# MongoDB (mongoose) Apply sort, filter on documents coming from 2 collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections with the following dummy schema

**alphas**

```
_id: ObjectId
title: String
status: String
```

**betas**

```
_id: ObjectId
title: String
alphaId: ObjectId
```

alphas sample documents

```
db.alphas.insert([
   { "_id" : 3, "title" : "almonds", status: "approved"},
   { "_id" : 1, "title" : "pecans", status: "approved"},
])
```

betas sample documents

```
db.betas.insert([
   { "_id" : 1, "title" : "neon", "alphaId" : "1" },
   { "_id" : 2, "title" : "argon", "alphaId" : "2"},
])
```

What I need is get a cursor that has documents of both these collections based on these conditions:

- All the betas
- All the alphas, whose status is 'approved' AND for which a beta does not exist (Identified by alphaId on beta collection).

```
[
   { "_id" : 1, "title" : "neon", "alphaId" : "1" },
   { "_id" : 2, "title" : "argon", "alphaId" : "2"},
   { "_id" : 3, "title" : "almonds", status: "approved"},
]
```

So eventually I can apply a sort on it like this

```
cursor.sort()
```

In the research that I have done so far, I found a way to populate document from `alpha` inside the document of `beta` using $lookup.

```
db.betas.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: {
          $exists: true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "alphas",
        localField: 'alphaId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'alphas'
      }
    },
]);
```

Is there a way I can get the documents of both in a flat structure, at the same level, so I can apply a mongo `sort` / `filter` on the whole thing.

Note: I can achieve this easily on the application layer, but that would be suboptimal. I'd like to use the DB layer to achieve this.

MongoDB version: 3.3.2

Comment: Show some sample documents and the output you want

Comment: Added them @Ashh